# Simple help with DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I am new to Mathematica in general. Just trying to solve a couple of coupled ODES. Dont really understand the error it throws.

```
DSolve[{y'[t] == A*x[t]/((x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)*(1 - R/Sqrt[(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)])), 
  x'[t] == A*y[t]/((x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)*(1 - R/Sqrt[(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)])),
   x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, t, 
 Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals, y \[Element] Reals].
```

This gives the error
"`DSolve::derlen`: The length of the derivative operator Derivative[1] in y'[t] is not the same as number of arguements." Now this system actually has a singularity if x^2+y^2=R. I just don't understand how to put in that as an assumption. I have tried "Assumptions-> x[t]^2+y[t]^2<R", it doesnt work. Moreover I have a physical understanding that if the system starts at x[0]=1 and y[0]=1 it should not reach this singularity since the solution would go in a circle around the centre. I might have made some superflous errors as well, so I am grateful for any help

Comment: Put braces `{}` around assumptions: `Assumptions -> {…..}`

Comment: You might want to report this to WRI as a bug. It probably ought to do a better job of parsing here, because an option precedes the `Element[y, Reals]` argument that looks like a domain spec. It’s an unhelpful error message in any case.

Comment: Miraculously, `DSolve` can find the general solution (remove the initial conditions). You’ll have to solve for the integration parameters yourself.  The solutions is rather complicated and it might be difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try “homogeneous” initial conditions:

```
DSolve[{y'[t] == A*x[t]/((x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)*(1 - R/Sqrt[(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)])), 
  x'[t] == A*y[t]/((x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)*(1 - R/Sqrt[(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)])),
   x[0] == a*R, y[0] == b*R}, 
 {x, y}, t]
(* long output *)
```

It gives two solutions, perhaps from rationalizing the square roots.  You should check which satisfy a particular initial conditions.

Comment: I tried it with some numerical value of R and A,with a,b<1 and x,y=Real, then it gives errors which state "For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary \
conditions lead to an empty solution" and "Unable to resolve some of the arbitrary constants in the general \ solution using the given boundary conditions. It is possible that \
some of the conditions have been specified at a singular point for \ the equation.". Which is interesting because if it starts from some radius lower than R and x and y are real then it should not hit singularity.

Comment: @SarthakChoudhury The boundary conditions are not easy equations to solve symbolically.  I would check the `DSolve` solution from my code against `NDSolve` for numerical values of `R` etc. You can plug values in with `mysol /. {R -> 2}` and so forth.  I wouldn't plug the numerical values into the ODEs and call `DSolve` again. (I guess I might try it, but I'm not surprised `DSolve` had trouble.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael E2. I really appreciate your help